# RAID Controller make interchangeability

Tags: raid

We are using LSI 9361-8i RAID Controller in one of the workstation.

Yesterday somehow controller stopped working. So we put AVAGO make 9361-8i controller at that time.

After importing all configuration, we re-booted the machine. During booting windows blue screen error appeared 0x0000007B ( 0xFFFFF880009B37E8,0xFFFFFFFFC0000034,0,0)

We are not able to start the windows in safe mode also but can login into last configuration with some programs were not working.

My question is does these controllers are make specific? or we can interchange same model with different make?

Thanks for sparing time and thanks in advance for the reply.

Comment: Even if the RAID chip is the same most likely the vendor ID and device ID is different so that Windows can't use the the installed LSI driver.

Comment: “We are not able to start the windows in safe mode also but can login into last configuration with some programs were not working.” This sentence doesn’t make any sense, but of course RAID controllers are manufacturer specific, sometimes they are model specific.  So your problems are likely connected to switching manufacturers

Comment: And firmware specific even when they are an exact hardware match, reinstall Windows.